# How to access Locu API

Tags: api

I am looking to use the Locu API, but I can't find a way to sign up or/and get an API key. I have looked on their website and can't figure out how to sign up. Does anybody know how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Locu no longer allows new developers to sign up.

Read the post: https://www.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/Locu-API-Access/td-p/33447