# Locu api alternatives for menu items?

Tags: api

This post suggest that Locu Api is no longer available

[How to access Locu API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540592/how-to-access-locu-api)

I am wondering is there an alternatives for restaurant menu api specifically for Yelp Dataset.